# Show progress of achievements post 5.0.4?

Tags: achievements, world-of-warcraft

So now that we've got account-wide achievements for all the characters, you can seemingly no longer toggle the convenient achievement tracker with the progress bar on your characters anymore.

Though this isn't really that big a deal for most achievements, it gave me a more *tangible* indicator of where I was in my progress in a given zone. I know that I can still Shift-click the achievement and see its header displayed on my screen, and then I can click that to see the progress bar in the Achievements window to see where I sit, but...

Is there a way that I can get the progress bar back on my screen to minimize clicks?

Comment: http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/overachiever adds the bar, even for achievements that did not usually have a bar but did have the information, but I am not sure if it dose it account wide or pr char since I haven't used it for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in method to do that, since as of 5.0.4 Blizzard UI code just checks if achievement is complete (which now means "complete on any character account-wide") and doesn't even bothers with checking and drawing requirements after that.

However, the data and [functions to retrieve objectives and counts](http://www.wowpedia.org/API_GetAchievementCriteriaInfo) are intact and return information relevant to current character, so this can be either fixed in UI by Blizzard later or implemented in an addon.

Either do it yourself or ask at some popular WoW UI programming forum in "addon ideas" section.